# How can one screen record part of the screen on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, screen-capture

Example:

[image]

The built-in screen recorder seems to be only able to record the entire screen. I know I could use that and then use [another application to crop the video](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/video-crop-resize-video/id1155649867) (this is how I created the example video above), but that takes a lot of space for long videos and I’d prefer to only record part of the screen instead of having to crop it after the recording.

I use iOS 15 on an iPhone 12.

Comment: For what it’s worth, you don’t need a third-party app to crop video: iOS Photos app can do it.

Comment: @grg thanks, good to know!

Comment: @grg I've just used the iOS Photos app to crop and trim a video for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392652/178179), great tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in screen recording feature does not support recording only part of the screen. Therefore you (or an app) must record the full screen and crop after the fact.

Comment: Thanks, good to know!